# Mapping two yield variables from a generator function

Tags: python, stream, mapping, yield

The code is as follow

```
def filee(filename):
    cpu = "iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1 = STRING:"
    newline = "\n"
    quotes = '"\n'
    file = open(filename)
    lineno = 0
    for line in file:
        lineno += 1
        linestriptime = line[line.find("(")+1:line.find(")")]
        linestripload = (line.strip(cpu + newline + '\n').replace('\"', ''))
        v = lineno % 2
        if v == 0:
            load = float(linestripload)
            yield (timestamp, load)
        else:
            timestamp = int(linestriptime)

listyield = filee("snmpfile.txt")

mappedload = {timestamp : load for (timestamp, load) in listyield}

print mappedload
```

Simply put, I want to map the timestamp and load yield variables from the generator function together but somehow the `print mappedload` command always give me an empty dictionary instead. Why does this happen and how can I map the two variables together?

EDIT: I've included this line of code, printing the yield value works just fine

```
print ("**************** TRAP LISTYIELD ***************")
for (timestamp, load) in listyield:
    print(timestamp, load)
print ("**************** END OF TRAP LISTYIELD ***************")
```

Result

```
**************** TRAP LISTYIELD ***************
(201607, 0.62)
(203174, 0.55)
(203336, 0.55)
(203479, 0.51)
(203611, 0.51)
(203731, 0.51)
**************** END OF TRAP LISTYIELD ***************
{}
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing to `yield`. Try printing before yielding.

Comment: I've included the result with the print function, it appears the printing works just fine

Comment: What happens if you move the line `mappedload = {timestamp : load for (timestamp, load) in listyield}` before the above `print`s ?

Comment: I..... don't know why but that works LOL It's now showing the dictionary

Comment: Generator objects can be only iterated **once**: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators.